# Let X be an exponential random variable with P(X < 1/3) = 0.75. What is E(X)?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let X be an exponential random variable with P(X < 1/3) = 0.75. What is E(X)?

I don't get this. Please help.

Comment: Hint: For an exponential random vairable the pdf is $f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x<0$. Use this to find $\lambda$. Then you have $E(x) = \int_0^\infty x f(x) dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exponential density is given by $f_\lambda(x) = \begin{cases}
\lambda e^{-\lambda x} & x \ge 0, \\
0 & x < 0.
\end{cases}$.

You can use $P(X<y)=\int_{-\infty}^{y} f_\lambda(x) dx$ with the given condition to determine $\lambda$.
 The final result can then be obtained by $E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_\lambda(x) dx$